# Spacing between the labels on pie plot matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

When I plot the pie chart, 'labels' are overlapping. I do understand that this is happening due to values being equal.
Is there a way to increase the spacing between labels along the perimeter of the pie chart.
I do not mind the last value label moving into the first pie value area.
The other solutions I saw on SO include plotting labels separately as a table but I would like it in the default format.
Thanking you in anticipation.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df99 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Data': ['A', 'B', 'C','D','E'],
    'Perc': [0.62, 0.31, 0.02,0.02,0.02]})
plt.pie(df99['Perc']*100, colors=['#002c4b','#392e2c','#92847a','#ccc2bb','#6b879d','#7FBAA4','#8E654C','#006CB8','#CBBBE9','#9778D3'],counterclock=False,startangle=-270,pctdistance=1.2,labeldistance=1.2,labels=df99['Data'],
        autopct=None)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I have a question for you. Copy paste your code in a fresh notebook/terminal and try running it. Do you get any errors? If yes, then rectify them and then add your working code to the question

Comment: Sorry about that. Will modify the question. Added values but did not add columns.

Answer (score -2):

You can rotate the labels with the rotatelabels parameter for a cleaner look.

Also, if you have many different labels, consider using a legend.

Edit: You can merely decrease the font size of labels to increase spacing, or increase the size of the figure.

```
fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(#, #))
```